# How to deal with function definitions in header files?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, header-files

Is there any way I can compile a poorly designed header file to a object file without changing file extension or content using gcc, or do I *have* to copy the file/edit it? (This because I am using a public SDK, i.e. I do not have permission to edit the header file, and because using `cp` in my Makefile seems like a major hack, and time consuming too)

## Example

#### main.c

```
#include <print.h>
#include <app.h>

int main(void) {
    print("Starting app . . . ");
    run();
}
```

#### app.h

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

int runApp(void);
#endif
```

#### app.c

```
#include <print.h>
#include <app.h>

int runApp(void) {
    print("This is my app!");
    return 0
}
```

#### print.h

```
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

int print(char* str) {
    printf(str);
    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Which is compiled using:

```
$ gcc -o main.o main.c
$ gcc -o app.o  app.c
$ gcc -o main   main.o app.o
```

The SDK example programs use a single object file (`gcc -o main.o main.c & gcc -o main main.o`), but that would just get really messy in my case.

Comment: The `print` function is insane in at least three different ways. Throw it away and never look back.

Comment: @KerrekSB I hope you realized that the `print` function is just a example?

Comment: "...compile a poorly designed header file to a object file..." - this already makes little sense. Header files are not supposed to be compiled into object files, regardless of whether they are poorly designed or not. So, what is it you want to do? Do you really want to compile that header file into object file? Is it required?

Answer (score 0):

Create

_print.h

```
int print(char* str);
```

print.cpp

```
#include <print.h>
```

and change your includes to `"_print.h"`

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Your requirements mean you can't include print.h multiple times.  You can create declarations in a new static file and include that.